# 301 Redirection of website URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, web-config, http-status-code-301

currently we have our website running like this:  websitename.com.  But we've added multiple languages to it so now all the English content will be available at websitename.com/en and the Russian content will be available at websitename.com/ru.  Google has already indexed the URLs at websitename.com.  Now, I want to redirect these URLs to default en.

i.e. websitename.com/page1 to websitename.com/en/page1
How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

> Redirection is one way to make sure that users always receive the Web
>   page that they want. Redirection refers to the process of configuring
>   the Web server to issue a redirect message to the client, such as HTTP
>   302, which instructs the client to resubmit the request for a new
>   location. You can redirect users to another file, directory, or site.

You can check MSDN article about [IIS Redicrection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx). Check the links in Procedures section.

Comment: These links are for redirection in those cases where the site is under construction or maintenance.  But I think, my case is different. I want all my current URLs on the website to have an '/en' suffix.